# Databinding issues on building app for release

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run an app ono release mode in my mobile. After click on run my message log is filled with these errors:

```
Warning:android.databinding.DataBindingUtil: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBinderMapper
Warning:android.databinding.DataBindingUtil: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent
Warning:android.databinding.ViewDataBinding: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBinderMapper
Warning:android.databinding.ViewDataBinding: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent
Warning:android.databinding.ViewDataBinding: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBinderMapper
Warning:android.databinding.ViewDataBinding: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:there were 46 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForStageRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

This is some part of my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.bom
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

Inserting `dataBinding{enabled true }` in the release part the errors drops to about 3.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleStageRelease]
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForStageRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

Your build is failing due to warnings from ProGuard. These aren't always blocking, and you can add a `-dontwarn` line to Proguard to get around them. The best thing to do is find which libraries the affected code is in, and find documentation from the library for what ProGuard rules are safe to add.